# Shoveling objects into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, screen-scraping

I'm working on scraping.

```
class MMA::School
    attr_accessor :name, :location_info, :url

    def self.today
        self.schools
    end

    def self.schools
        schools = []
        schools << self.scrape_cbs
        schools
    end

    def self.scrape_cbs
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://newyork.cbslocal.com/top-lists/5-best-mma-and-martial-arts-studios-in-new-york/"))

        schools_1 = self.new
        schools_1.name = doc.search("//div/p/strong/span").text.strip
        schools_1.location_info = doc.search("//div/p")[4].text.strip
        schools_1.url = doc.search("//div/p/a")[0].text.strip

        schools_1

        schools_2 = self.new
        schools_2.name = doc.search("//div/p/span")[0].text.strip
        schools_2.location_info = doc.search("//div/p")[7].text.strip
        schools_2.url = doc.search("//div/p/a")[2].text.strip

        schools_2

        schools_3 = self.new
        schools_3.name = doc.search("//div/p/span")[1].text.strip
        schools_3.location_info = doc.search("//div/p")[9].text.strip
        schools_3.url = doc.search("//div/p/a")[3].text.strip

        schools_3

        schools_4 = self.new
        schools_4.name = doc.search("//div/p/span")[2].text.strip
        schools_4.location_info = doc.search("//div/p")[12].text.strip
        schools_4.url = doc.search("//div/p/a")[5].text.strip

        schools_4

        schools_5 = self.new
        schools_5.name = doc.search("//div/p/span")[3].text.strip
        schools_5.location_info = doc.search("//div/p")[14].text.strip
        schools_5.url = doc.search("//div/p/a")[6].text.strip

        schools_5
    end   
end
```

I have some trouble placing my scraped data into an empty array. It only pushes one of the `schools_1` etc. to the `schools` array.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Without any explanation, it is absolutely not clear what you are trying to do, but it is clear that in your `self.scrape_cbs` definition, the lines:

```
schools_1
...
schools_2
...
...
schools_4
```

are meaningless. Perhaps, you intended to return an array like this from this method:

```
[schools_1, schools_2, ..., schools_5]
```

If so, put the line above as the last line of your method definition of `self.scrape_cbs`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear...I'm trying to get the scraped data from school_1 to school_5 into: def self.schools
        schools = []
        schools << self.scrape_cbs
        schools
    end

Comment: That is what I suggested in my answer above.

Comment: Wait a minute...I wrote a whole paragraph explaining what the problem was and you, @sawa, edited it out  to just have it say "I'm working on scraping." WTF!!! is that about????